# IE11: very poor perfomance in rendering tables - any solutions?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

My Dom-structure looks like this:

[image]

On my html-webpage there are 226 divs with corresponding ids from "content-box1" to "content_box226". Each of these contentboxes contain a svg-picture and a html-table-with css-colouring. Only one  content-box is shown at the same time. The navigation through the content-boxes is managed by a html-selectbox and jQuery.

My problem is that this webpage is lacking in IE11 like hell. Why? Is InterExplorer11 rendering all svgs and tables of all content-boxes despite of the fact that only one content-box is shown? How i can avoid this behavior?

Comment: do you display everything at the start then hide it? or are your content boxes default hidden with CSS?

Comment: the content boxes are default hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSS, performance wise

```
visiblilty: hidden;
```

is better than

```
display: none;
```